# Bounded Linear Operators and their norms

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=(\ell_3,\Vert\cdot\Vert_3)$. Fix $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $M:X\to X$ be the linear operator defined by:
\begin{equation*}
  M(x) = (zx_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots)
 \end{equation*}
Check whether or not $M$ is a bounded linear operator.

My Attempt: Let $x\in X $, then
\begin{align}
  \Vert M(x)\Vert_3^3 &= z^3x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3+\cdots \\
       &= z^3x_1^3 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}|x_k|^3\\
       &\leq \max\{1,z\}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^3 \\
       &=\max\{1,z\} \Vert x \Vert_3^3
 \end{align}
take the vector $x = (1,0,0,0,0.\dots)$. Then $\Vert M \Vert$ = $\max\{1,z\}$

Comment: Yes, your result is true but you need $||x||_3=1$ as well when you are taking $x$ from $X$. And the vector $x=(1,0,0....)$ is a good example.

Comment: Absolute value signs missing. You also need something like $(0,1,0,0,...)$ ot show that $\|M\| \geq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh yes the absolute value signs. I don't get the second part of your comment, that is, to show that $\Vert M \Vert \geq 1$.